# Embed manifest file to require administrator execution level with mingw32

Tags: c, linux, windows, uac, mingw32

I'm cross compiling an application with i586-mingw32msvc under ubuntu.

I'm having difficulties understanding how to embed a manifest file to require administrator execution level with mingw32.

For my example I used this `hello.c`:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

this resource file `hello.rc`:

```
1 Manifest "hello.exe.manifest"
```

this manifest file `hello.exe.manifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="hello" type="win32"/> 
    <description>Hello World</description> 
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

I compile my resource file with:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-windres hello.rc hello.o
```

I compile my final application with:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -O3 -Os -s -o hello.exe hello.c hello.o
```

[SigCheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) does not show the manifest file running `sigcheck -m hello.exe`.

Now when I run my application under Windows it does not trigger the UAC (=does not run as administrator) while when I attach the `hello.exe.manifest` file in the same folder it does trigger the UAC (as expected).

What did I miss?

**EDIT1:** Playing with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker) I've opened a `Setup.exe` file I've created with NSIS, the only sensible difference is that `Manifest` is written `MANIFEST` in my `hello.exe` and `Manifest` in `Setup.exe` though in `hello.rc` it's written Manifest. O_o

[image: NSIS Installer vs hello.exe]

**EDIT2:** I've changed the `Manifest` group manually with Resource Hacker:

[image: Modified with Resource Hacker]

Now `hello.exe` is acting normally triggering the UAC alert and running as an administrator. Seems like a "bug" with `i586-mingw32msvc-windres`. :-)

Comment: This may help: http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/win32-apps-with-mingw/

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you but I've tried what's described on that link too.. and [the link it linked to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756973.aspx) too.. But nothing changed.. I've updated my `hello.rc` file to `1 Manifest "hello.exe.manifest"`.. With Resource Hacker I've opened an NSIS installer (I've compiled with makensis) that requires administrator, everything is sensibly the same; the only thing that is different is the manifest field is written "Manifest" in the `Setup.exe` file and written "MANIFEST" in my `hello.exe` file! ([See here](http://i.imgur.com/WzHtXnw.png))

Comment: Normally you compile .rc file to `.res` file (not `.o`)

Comment: please help me, where are the imgur pictures ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With regard to the magic voodoo numbers 1 and 24:

```
1 24 "hello.exe.manifest"
```

That line translates to somthing like this:

```
ID_MANIFEST RT_MANIFEST "hello.exe.manifest"
```

where those defines are as defined as follows:

```
#define ID_MANIFEST 1
#ifndef RT_MANIFEST
#define RT_MANIFEST MAKEINTRESOURCE(24)
#endif
```

As shown above by the conditional wrappers, the *RT_MANIFEST* might already be defined and if you do a Google search for that *RT_MANIFEST* term you will find lots of hits with more details on what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

With some intense voodoo I got it to work with this on my `hello.rc` file:

```
1 24 "hello.exe.manifest"
```

Won't even search to know what the 24 is for (resource type manifest?!).. :-)